# how to create a pointer of pointer type class in c#

Tags: c#, c++

i have a example to this question so :

i have a class "q_bit " and i want to create a pointer m_q_bit like this code in c++

```
q_bit **m_q_bit
```

how i can create this by c#

Comment: Objection, there are pointers in C# http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/355774-pointers-in-c%23/

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to achieve? Yes there are pointers, but *why* do you need one?

Comment: i want to do thats in c#
 for(int i=0; i<nbr_poit; i++){
 m_q_bit[i]=new q_bit();}
q_bit is a class and m_q_bit pointer . my problem is how to creat a pointer in c# like this in c++ 
q_bit **m_q_bit

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do this instead of using managed code, but if you'd really want to you would need to write an unsafe struct q_bit that does not use managed types and implement an unsafe implicit cast of qbit[] (assuming that you are using a q_bit[]) that returns the pointer to the first element of the managed array. The problem is that there is no way that I know of to do the last step.

Answer (score -1):

Like this?

```
q_bit* m_q_bit = new q_bit(/*Enter constructor values as needed/*);
```